# cannot solve null exception error

Tags: java, exception, object, null

I am creating an object orientated mastermind game. I have all the classes and methods set-up and have tried them in a non object orientated programming style and they all work but now since I have them in object orientated style I get the null pointer error. It tells me where the error is occurring and I have tried to figure out what is the null value or what is wrong but I cannot figure it out. I have also tried taking out the point where the null happens just to get another null exception at a similar type expression. So I believe that I have the syntax wrong for invoking methods or such but do not know how to fix it or if it's the cause of the real error.

The second code block is where the error occurs if you want to jump straight to it.

I know I've posted a lot of stuff here so if you need any clarification I'll gladly help. The main focus is just the null error so if there is some other error that you see just ignore it unless it impedes on solving the null error.

I separated each class for easier reading.

---

```
public class GameTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MasterMind m = new MasterMind();
    m.playGame();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MasterMind 
{
private Master theMaster;
private Player thePlayer;

public void mastermind() {
    theMaster = new Master();
    thePlayer = new Player();
}

public void playGame() {
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO CODEBREAKER... Let's Play!\n");
    System.out.println("Guess a 4-letter code with letters A, B, C, and D\n");

    theMaster.createCode(); //heres where the null exception is said to occur

    while(true) {
        thePlayer.makeGuess(); //if i remove the call above this becomes null error
        int x = theMaster.totalCorrect(thePlayer.getGuess());
        if( x == 4) {
            System.out.println("\nGOT IT!!!\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("MISSED! %d out of 4. TRY AGAIN... \n", x);
        }       
    }
 }
```

---

```
  import java.util.Random;
  public class Master 
  {
  private char[] Code = new char[4];

public Master()
{

}

public void createCode()
{
     Random R = new Random();
        char[] setting ={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}; 
        int rx;

        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
            rx = R.nextInt(4);
            Code[i] = setting[rx];
        }           
}

public int totalCorrect(char[] theGuess)
{
    int x =0;

    if(Code[0] == theGuess[0]) {
        x++;
    }   
    if(Code[1] == theGuess[1]) {
        x++;
    }
    if(Code[2] == theGuess[2]) {
        x++;
    }
    if(Code[3] == theGuess[3]) {
        x++;
    }

    return x;
}
}
```

---

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Player { 

 private char[] Guess = new char[4];

public Player() {

}

public void makeGuess() {

    System.out.println("YOUR GUESS => ");
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = input.next(); 
    char[] D = guess.toCharArray(); 

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Guess[i] = D[i];
    }   
}

public char[] getGuess() {
        return Guess;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using final on attribute declaration you enforce the life-cycle of the instances, and you don't need a constructor:

```
public class MasterMind 
{
   private final Master theMaster = new Master();
   private final Player thePlayer = new Player();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor should be exact same class and no return type. Otherwise it will be treated as method and won't execute on object instantiation, which leaves `theMaster` reference pointing to `null`.

```
 MasterMind () 
{
    theMaster = new Master();
    thePlayer = new Player();

}
```

Comment: @Vulcan: I was typing explanation and saw your comment.

Comment: yeah i get what you mean about the constructor but do not understand what you mean about the return type. thank you for the fast response too!

Comment: @charahri Constructors do not return anything. When you create objects with new an error can be thrown when creating an object. Though constructor do not return a value; only new does.

Comment: @charahri: You don;t need to define void. void is a return type which tells nothing will be returned as result of execution of this operation.

Comment: I'd like to note that constructors internally *do* have return types of their enclosing class, but for a learner's purpose, that knowledge shouldn't be too relevant.  However, they don't have a declared return type, so great answer.

Comment: @TheBlueCat: I agree with your comment on static, but without full context I was hesitant to suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: @Vulcan: I think at this point, it would be too much for OP to digest.

Comment: @Nambari You answered the question. I was just suggesting possible suggestions to the OP - his code is not 'very coherent', his classes do not share as 'is a' relationship, they just need to a bit of attention or the need for the OP to read a book.

Comment: @Vulcan do you mean anonymous inner classes/inner classes?

Comment: @TheBlueCat sorry if my code is messy. but then agian i am learning and all you input is greatly apreciated. also what book would you suggest then since i have just been using the text book assigned to me in my class?

Comment: @charahri The comment section is not meant for this - either look at SO or download my booklist from S3 https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/jv-c-programming/programming/booklist.linux

Comment: @TheBlueCat I don't mean anonymous classes.

Comment: @Vulcan can you explain then?

Comment: @TheBlueCat Take a look at the bytecode of a call to a constructor.  You'll see that it in fact does have a return type, and the return type is the type of the class that the constructor instantiates.

Comment: @Vulcan Of course - this is more associated with the 'new' rather than the constructor as such. I'll take your word for it though  - I don't usually delve into the bytecode unless I have a nagging bug that I can't fix with books or Google.

Answer (score 0):

**-** First you should have a `constructor` with the **name** of the `Class`, and **with No** `return type`.

**-** A `method` can have **same name** as the `class` but will **have a** `return type`.

**Try something like this:**

```
MasterMind () 
{
    theMaster = new Master();
    thePlayer = new Player();

}
```